# Pyspark has different versions in driver (python3.5) and worker(python2.7)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, hdfs

I am using both hdfs and normal user mode.Default Python version in local is 3.5 and in hdfs is 2.7.This error popped up when I was trying to load files in hdfs and trying to display it in jupyter.

[image]

I tried to edit the spark-env.sh file.But when I looked for it there are multple spark -env.sh files and I edited all of them but in vain.I found similar questions in stack overflow, but nothing seems to work and suit my particluar problem.

**If you require information on anything, please let me know in the comments, as I dont know what kind of information is required here.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the following [environment variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) in your spark-env.sh point to python binary executables with the same(!) version on all(!) your nodes:

- PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
- PYSPARK_PYTHON

If PYSPARK_PYTHON is currently not set, please set it. PYSPARK_PYTHON defines the executable for executor and driver. When you only set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON to python3.5, the executor will still use the default python executeable which is python2.7 and this raise the exeception you see.